# Changing the hour with datetime.replace() in python

Tags: python, macos, datetime

Given that foo is a valid datetime object in python,

One can change the hour represented in a datestamp (foo) by doing something something like:

```
foo2 = foo.replace( hour=5 )
```

Rather then replacing the hour with a particular value ( as is done above )..is it possible to increment the time in foo by say, 5 hours ? Something along the lines of:

```
foo2 = foo.replace( hour += 5 )
```

Which I know is not correct...but maybe that explains better what I am aiming to do...

I am limited to using python 2.5.1 ( the version on OS X 10.5.x) .. and am not able to add any modules such as pyTZ

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's what `timedelta` is for:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 25, 18, 25)
>>> d + datetime.timedelta(hours = 8)
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 26, 2, 25)
```